# Python: Popen.wait returns 1 even is the execution is successful

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the below code to execute a command and get the output.

```
import os, sys, subprocess, string
def executeCommand(execstr):
    print "cmd: " + execstr
    p = subprocess.Popen(execstr, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = ""
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    p_status = p.wait()

    if (p_status != 0):
        print "Unable to execute "+ execstr

    return (string.strip(output))

cmd = "grep -R \"pattern\" sample.txt"
output = executeCommand(cmd)
print "output: "  +output
```

Here p_status returned from p.wait() is 1 (non zero)
When executing the command in command line its successful. 
sample.txt is a empty text file. 
err from p.communicate is None. 
What is wrong in the above code.

Comment: unrelated: without `stderr=PIPE` `err` is *always* `None`. Drop `shell=True` and use `shlex.split(execstr)`.

Comment: So, to get the err, from p.communicate(), stderr=subprocess.PIPE, needs to be added to the Popen command?

Comment: yes. It is explicitly mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

[`grep` can return non-zero status even if there are no errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Exit-Status).

It returns `1` if it hasn't found anything. It returns `2` (or greater) on errors.

Comment: Thanks! Didnt notice that p.wait return the exit code of the the child process.